# Replace/Substitute ALL values in a dataframe with values referenced from another dataframe (not a merge)

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, substitution

I have a dataframe with four variables and list of brands. I need to replace/substitute the brand name values referencing values from another dataframe. The data I've created is fictional but hopefully provides a real world example of why I would need something like this. Let's say the variables represent four teams and those are the brands the teams work on. Sometimes we'd need to rename a brand to be anonimised to "Brand X".
This is the dataframe for the teams and the brands

```
team_a <- c("Apple", "IBM", "HSBC", "BA", "Diageo", "","")
team_b <- c("Microsoft", "Google", "Asus", "Bethesda", "HSBC", "Pernod", "Diageo")
team_c <- c("Facebook", "Samsung", "BMW", "Google", "P&G", "Sony", "")
team_d<- c("IBM", "Apple", "Microsoft", "Facebook", "HSBC", "McDonalds", "")
df <- data.frame(team_a, team_b, team_c, team_d)

> df
  team_a    team_b   team_c    team_d
1  Apple Microsoft Facebook       IBM
2    IBM    Google  Samsung     Apple
3   HSBC      Asus      BMW Microsoft
4     BA  Bethesda   Google  Facebook
5 Diageo      HSBC      P&G      HSBC
6           Pernod     Sony McDonalds
7           Diageo
```

This is the reference dataframe

```
Old_Name <- c("Apple", "Facebook", "Google")
New_Name <- c("Brand X", "Brand Y", "Brand Z")
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(Old_Name,New_Name))

> df2
  Old_Name New_Name
1    Apple  Brand X
2 Facebook  Brand Y
3   Google  Brand Z
```

The final dataframe should look like this

```
> df
   team_a    team_b  team_c    team_d
1 Brand X Microsoft Brand Y       IBM
2     IBM   Brand Z Samsung   Brand X
3    HSBC      Asus     BMW Microsoft
4      BA  Bethesda Brand Z   Brand Y
5  Diageo      HSBC     P&G      HSBC
6            Pernod    Sony McDonalds
7            Diageo
```

Of course, I can do this way manually for each brand

```
df[df=="Apple"] <- "Brand X"
```

However using a replace/substitute function with a reference dataframe would be far more efficient. I've been searching with little luck. Most examples i've seen are based on one variable so people have been using a merge/replace route. This is across multiple variables and I can't see a way to use merge. If there is a method to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated, or if you can point me in the direction of the right package/function that would also be great too. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to create a named vector (`deframe`) from the reference dataset ('df2'), loop over the columns of the dataset ('df') with `across`, use the named vector to match and replace the elements where it matches, while the non-match returns as `NA`, then replace the `NA` with the original column values using `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.0.0
library(tibble)
df %>% 
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ coalesce(deframe(df2)[.], .)))
#   team_a    team_b  team_c    team_d
#1 Brand X Microsoft Brand Y       IBM
#2     IBM   Brand Z Samsung   Brand X
#3    HSBC      Asus     BMW Microsoft
#4      BA  Bethesda Brand Z   Brand Y
#5  Diageo      HSBC     P&G      HSBC
#6            Pernod    Sony McDonalds
#7            Diageo
```

Comment: thanks for explaining those steps. I tried going down that route, but i didn't now how to replace NA with original. Thanks